# Why is % forbidden char in THROW message?

Tags: sql-server

Simple question:

```
THROW 50000, 'Because of this ->%<- is this message invisible.', 1;
```

- you can't pass %s, %d parameters as in RAISERROR
- you have to use FORMATMESSAGE
- but THROW failed anyway if % is not doubled (correct displaying)

Tested on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) 11.0.3381.0 (X64), 11.0.3000.0 (X64)

---

Real world example:

```
DECLARE @ProcParam VARCHAR(30) = 'Hehe%x!';
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(500) = FORMATMESSAGE('Procedure input %s is wrong', @ProcParam);
PRINT 'Message: ' + @Message;
THROW 50000, @Message, 1;
```

Comment: @swasheck Really? I have only "Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 1", without message.

Comment: nope. sorry. i was incorrect. i was looking at two different things :S

Comment: It's interesting to note that if you put a space `char(32)` after the % it will display the message (sans %)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that they left the `printf` functionality (or at least part of it) in the THROW command but did not include a way to pass in a parameter to it.  I tried each of the characters listed in BOL for [RAISEERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) as possible "types" `%(d, i, o, s, x, X, or u)` and each of them gave back a blank.  Any other character after the % and you get back a valid string.  My guess is that they are replacing the value with a `NULL` which of course causes any string concatenation to return a `NULL` and when printed looks blank.

Unfortunately without the code behind it (or at least a MS Developer) to confirm there is no way to be certain.

Comment: Not quite - `%n` for example will be treated as `\n` (try it out). I'm getting confirmation from Microsoft folks and will post a more thorough explanation when I get one.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right.  I went back and checked and got a blank line for a-z (except n) and 1-9.  I'm looking forward to seeing what you find out.

Comment: This is so sad. They gave us working Exceptions (finally!) but instantly broke it. Message parameters are gone and they even managed to keep some parameter-related code, just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kenneth Fisher ... the value is replaced with `NULL` ...

```
DECLARE @ProcParam VARCHAR(30) = 'Hehe%x!';
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(500) = FORMATMESSAGE('Procedure input ' + @ProcParam + ' is wrong');
THROW 50000, @Message, 1;

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Procedure input Hehe(null)! is wrong
```

Comment: It is not true. You pass %s as FORMATMESSAGE parameter (because you join strings using plus) but you didn't specify any true parameters for replacing. You are calling:  FORMATMESSAGE('Error value: %s', NULL, NULL, ... ...)